# Is there a multiple function composition operator?

Tags: notation, function-and-relation-composition

Is there a commonly-accepted operator which defines multiple function composition? I have not been able to find one on any of the related Wikipedia pages. In one of my proofs, I've been finding it very tiresome to continually write the following:
$$
f_n\circ f_{n-1}\circ\cdots\circ f_0
$$
And I would really appreciate finding out if there is a common notation for what I'm trying to do. The above notation only works for a sequence of functions; I imagine there's probably a way of using this composition operator to compose over an arbitrary ordered set, sort of like $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ allows a union over any (not necessarily countable) indexing set $I$, but without the ordering condition.

I'd use `foldl1 (.)`, but that doesn't seem very appropriate for math homework.

---

I feel like I should add why I feel like one is necessary, on top of the additional expressiveness we gain from being able to compose over arbitrary ordered sets. The problem itself defines $F_n$ as the above repeated-composition function; indeed, we can define $F_n$ in a recursive manner with $F_0=f_0$ and $F_{n+1}=f_{n+1}\circ F_n$. However, the issue remains because in my proof I frequently need to expand $F_n$ (for instance, calculating $F_n'$), in which case such an operator would come in handy.

Answer (score 4):

If I were writing something in which I had to do a large number of these, the following is probably not quite what I would do:
$$
\mathop{\bigcirc}^n_{k=0} f_k \quad \text{ or } \quad \mathop{\bigcirc}^0_{k=n} f_k \ .
$$
Instead, I'd go over to [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com) and ask how to make this thing look respectable instead of like a workaround.  I'd probably want it to be comparable in size and boldness to something like $\displaystyle\bigcap$ in $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=0}^n A_k$ or to $\displaystyle\bigoplus$.  Before the `\begin{document}` I'd put

```
\newcommand{\Circ}{blah blah blah}
```

with a capital `C` distinguishing it from `\circ`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm not $\LaTeX$-ing this assignment (for reasons that are not relevant). It seems that no such notation exists, then? I was hoping someone could have come across something in a paper they read before.

Comment: I haven't seen such a notation.  But sometimes one sees things like $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^n\frac\partial{\partial x_k}$ for composition of differential operators. If I were writing something by hand I might just write something like "In the following the notation $\mathop{\bigcirc}^{n}_{k=0} f_k$ will mean $f_n\circ\cdots\circ f_0$." ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I would be comfortable with that circle notation for functions which commute with each other.  Otherwise, I would keep being confused which index was evaluated first!

Answer (score 0):

I personally write $f_n\cdots f_0$ for the composition (possibly based on the analogy of multiplying matrices for composition of linear transformations).

Alternatively, you could let finite sequences stand for functions. For $F=\{f_i\}_{i=0}^n$ say $F$ is a function defined by $F(x)=f_n(\cdots f_1(f_0(x))\cdots)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n(x)$ be a sequence of functions indexed by $n$.

Define a new sequence of functions $F_k(x)$ indexed by $k$:

$$
F_k(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f_0(x) &: k=0\\
(f_k\circ F_{k-1})(x)&: k\gt 0
\end{cases}
$$

So you have, for example
$$
\begin{align}
F_0(x) &= f_0(x)\\
F_1(x) &= (f_1 \circ f_0)(x)\\
F_2(x) &= (f_2 \circ F_1)(x) = (f_2 \circ f_1 \circ f_0)(x)\\
&\dots\\
F_{n}(x) &= (f_n\circ f_{n-1} \circ \cdots \circ f_0)(x)\\
\end{align}
$$

Then for your composition $f_n\circ f_{n-1} \circ \cdots \circ f_0$ of $n$ terms you can simply write $F_n$.

Of course you can define a new sequence $G_n$ for the ascending direction, i.e., $G_2 = f_0 \circ f_1 \circ f_2$.