# Multiple composition of function notation

Tags: functions, notation

Let's say I have a set of $n$ functions of $m$ variables: $$f_1(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m),f_2(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m),\ldots,f_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)$$

Is there a notation that represents $(f_1 \circ f_2 \circ \cdots \circ f_n)(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m)$?

Basically, is there an equivalent of $\sum$, $\prod$, $\bigcup$, etc. for function composition? I have looked at several other threads on this site regarding this, but I have not found one containing a definite answer that satisfies me.

Comment: do the $f_i$'s also have $m$ components? otherwise the composition isn't well-defined. As for the proper question, there is no common symbol for $n$ times composition.

Comment: Maybe that helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926247/notation-for-repeated-composition-of-functions, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1097059/is-there-a-multiple-function-composition-operator